# Perl Script to ssh and rename file

Tags: perl

I am really new to perl scripting, and what I'd like is to ssh csv files from server A and rename them after they have been transferred.

Server

> A:/dirA/DIAMETER_Requests_\w+.csv==>transfer to Server B:/dirB/

and then rename them in Server

> A:/dirA/DIAMETER_Requests_\w+.csv ==> Server
>
> A:/dirA/DIAMETER_Requests_\w+.csv.old

I have managed to rename them but I am not sure how to go by with adding ssh option

Any help is very much appreciated!

```
#!/bin/perl
#

    @result = ();
    open (IN_FILE, "/dirA/DIAMETER_Requests_\w+.csv$") ||
        die ("ERROR: Cannot open file '/dirA/DIAMETER_Requests_\w+.csv$': $!\n");
    while (defined ($line = <IN_FILE>))
    {
        push (@result, $line);
    }
    close (IN_FILE);
    open (OUT_FILE, ">/dirA/DIAMETER_Requests_\w+.old.csv$") ||
        die ("ERROR: Cannot create file '/dirA/DIAMETER_Requests_\w+.old.csv$': $!\n");
    print OUT_FILE join ("", @result);
    close (OUT_FILE);

#   The end
    exit (0)
```

Comment: Even as Perl developer my advice would be to use 'bash' for this purpose. Try to find something by 'bash scp file with rename'

Comment: i dont think you should use system commands when perl gives you module to do all this very easily. If you use system modules like scp and if someone updates the modules by mistake your program may stop working. I would suggest to use Net::FTP module.

Comment: You haven't renamed anything. What you've done here is to copy the contents of the old file to a new file in a rather inefficient manner. Perhaps no-one has shown you Perl's [rename](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) function.

Comment: Also, do you really have a file that is actually called `DIAMETER_Requests_\w+.csv`? It seems far more likely to me that the `\w+` indicates that this is a regular expression which defines the format of your filenames.

Comment: I am using an internal tool developed by the company to transfer the file, and I put a general regex for that file name. Hence the "w"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH), no need to first copy and then rename file at the remote server:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $host = 'user@some.domain.com';
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
$ssh->error and
  die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
$ssh->scp_put("DIAMETER.csv", "DIAMETER.old.csv")
  or die "scp failed: " . $ssh->error;

my $async = 1;
$ssh->disconnect( $async );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this module which is inbuilt in perl for FTP and easily achieve what you want. Below code is also taken from the docs of Net::FTP [Net::FTP](https://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html)

```
    use Net::FTP;
    $ftp = Net::FTP->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0)
      or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";
    $ftp->login("anonymous",'-anonymous@')
      or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
    $ftp->cwd("/pub")
      or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;
    $ftp->get("actual_file_name","filename_to_be_changed")
      or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;
    $ftp->quit;
```

To access SFTP server just take a look at [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) module of perl.